# I installed tensorflow successfully, but when i tried to import tensorflow the error was shown like this : can any one help me for this ? thank you

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

File "c:\users\w\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_api\v2_*internal*_\distribute\interim_*init*_.py", line 8, in 
from tensorflow.python.distribute.merge_call_interim import maybe_merge_call

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.distribute.merge_call_interim'

Comment: Can you share the complete error traceback and exact import statement. I installed latest Tensorflow version 2.8.0. When i tried `import tensorflow`. It works just fine. Thanks!